# how can i put a rule that will only let you enter a number in a console application on C#

Tags: c#, numbers, coding-style, case-sensitive

so my problem is that when the user enters an letter it kind of crashes my console app haha now i want to put a validation in my code that will ask them to re-enter every time they enter a letter that is not a number but am having trouble doing so :( i have other methods that i would like to implement the answer on to as well, thank you guys.

```
   {

        double r;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the radius: ");
        r = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double areaCircle = pi * (r * r);
        Console.WriteLine("Radius: {0}, Area: {1}", r, areaCircle);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I validate console input as integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804968/how-can-i-validate-console-input-as-integers)

Comment: Have a look at `Int32.TryParse`.

Comment: And possible duplicate as well of [How do I only allow number input into my C# Console Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106493/how-do-i-only-allow-number-input-into-my-c-sharp-console-application)

Answer (score 2):

```
double userInput;
while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your input was not numeric. Please enter a number.");
}
```

When the `while` loop has exited, `userInput` will contain a `double` parsed from `Console.ReadLine()`.

If you're doing this more than once then I'd write a function. You probably also need a positive number.

```
double GetInput(string prompt)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    double userInput;
    while(!(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput) && userInput > 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive number.");
    }
    return userInput;
}
```

Then

```
var r = GetInput("Please enter the radius:");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse

```
{

   double r;
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the radius: ");
   Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out r);
   double areaCircle = pi * (r * r);
   Console.WriteLine("Radius: {0}, Area: {1}", r, areaCircle);
   Console.ReadLine();

 }
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of overkill to use a try catch when some simple validation would probably do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Convert.ToDouble, use TryParse instead:

```
    double r;
    string line;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the radius: ");
    line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (double.TryParse(line, out r))
    {
        double areaCircle = pi * (r * r);
        Console.WriteLine("Radius: {0}, Area: {1}", r, areaCircle);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

To make this more robust, try using a while loop to ensure you get valid input.