# Noob needing help on breaking out of loop

Tags: c#

I'm very sorry this is such an easy question, I'm just starting out. I've created code that allows a user to enter a number of random dice rolls, and outputs the sum of those rolls. I've now been asked to create a loop that repeats these steps, including the prompt, until the user types 'quit'. My issue is that my code converts the string to an integer, so typing anything kills the code. Any tips of how to insert the loop and break? My code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of dice to roll:");
    string numberDiceString = Console.ReadLine();
    int numberDice = Convert.ToInt32(numberDiceString);

    int total = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < numberDice; index++)
    {
        int DieRoll = random.Next(6) + 1;
        total += DieRoll;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(total);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Look for `"quit"` before you do the conversion.

Comment: It's C#.  The currently-posted code should be sufficient.

Comment: **Hint:** Use a `while` loop.  Put the code you want to repeat inside the loop.  Check for the string "quit" in the `while` condition.  You'll need two Console.Readline calls; one just before the loop, the other just before the loop's closing brace.

Comment: Int32.TryParse(String s, out int result) returns False if conversion fails. It will secure app from crashing.

Comment: @JayElston While I agree with what you want to express, we almost never want any "entire code". What we usually want is a [mcve]. Use this shortcut in future similar comments `[mcve]`.

Comment: You need to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106493/how-do-i-only-allow-number-input-into-my-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: @AussieJoe Do you mean it is a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I've not yet learned parsing so can't implement most solutions, but see useful tips throughout. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change should be fairly simple. What you need to do is to create a while loop, and then a check before you actually parse for an int. The psuedocode for this would be something like.

```
while(true) {
//Ask for input 
//Check if it equals "quit" 
//If so -> break; 
//If not convert to int
//For Loop for dice rolls
//Print Total
}
```

I'm sure it could be a little more elegant than this, and you would want to put some more checks to make sure that invalid input doesn't crash the program, but it should get the job done.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. While I appreciate all the other tips, many were using things I haven't learned yet. Your technique is pure order and enabled me to complete it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. If you think this is the right answer to your question, make sure to mark it as such so others will see!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a "while(true)" statement. As someone pointed out in the comments i would prefer using the right condition in there. 
That being said i would do it this way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    string numberDiceString;
    int numberDice;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of dice to roll:");
    while ((numberDiceString = Console.ReadLine()) != "quit")
    {
        bool parsed = int.TryParse(numberDiceString, out numberDice);
        if (!parsed)
        {
            //Handle the error. The user input was not a number or "quit" word
            break;
        }
        int total = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < numberDice; index++)
        {
            int DieRoll = random.Next(6) + 1;
            total += DieRoll;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(total);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of dice to roll:");
    }
}
```

I have to say that i prefer this way because you can easily see when the loop will stop. Also i added an error handling that you should be doing (What happen if the user enters any words that are not numbers?).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution that shows how to parse the user input.

```
using System;

namespace Simpleton
{
    class Program
    {
        static public int GetChoice()
        {
            int choice = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number of rolls or \"quit\" to finish: ");
                var answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (String.Compare(answer, "quit", true) == 0)
                {
                    return 0; // Done
                }
                if (Int32.TryParse(answer, out choice))
                {
                    return choice;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var choice = 0;
            while ((choice = GetChoice()) > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"You'll be looping {choice} times.");
                for (int tries = 0; tries < choice; tries++)
                {
                    // Looping
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        while(true)
        {
            String numberDiceString = "";
            int numberDice = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of dice to roll:");
            numberDiceString = Console.ReadLine();
            if (numberDiceString == "quit") { return; }
            int total = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(numberDiceString, out numberDice))
            {
                total = 0;

                for (int index = 0; index < numberDice; index++)
                {
                    int DieRoll = random.Next(6) + 1;
                    total += DieRoll;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a C# programmer, but you can test for "quit" explicitly and use a [goto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto)

```
BeginLoop:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of dice to roll:");
    string numberDiceString = Console.ReadLine();
    if (numberDiceString == "quit")
    {
        goto EndLoop;
    }
    int numberDice = Convert.ToInt32(numberDiceString);

    /* Rest of code you want to do per iteration */

    goto BeginLoop;

EndLoop:
```

Comment: I'm going to downvote for two reasons.  1) No need not to use a traditional loop structure (`goto BeginLoop` is not needed) and 2) `break` is preferred to `goto EndLoop`.

Comment: The basic idea here of comparing the string to test for "quit" before attempting to parse an integer is totally reasonable though.