# C# How to make repeated input overlap?

Tags: c#

When the input's type is not an integer, the program should fail. However, there are two problems:

1. After a letter is typed and I get the "not valid" response, then if the next input is a number, it won't accept it and says "not valid".
2. How can I make it so when a wrong number is inputted, it stays on the same row and just clears the previous input from the screen (and allows for a retry from the same position)?

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int firstNum;
       int Operation = 1;

       switch (Operation)
       {
           case 1:
               Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
               Console.Write("Write a number: ");
               firstNum = ReadInteger("");
               Console.ReadKey();
               break;
       }
   }

   private static int ReadInteger(string title)
   {
       while (true)
       {
           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
               Console.WriteLine(title);

           string input = Console.ReadLine();

           if (int.TryParse(input, out int result))
               return result;

           Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a valid integer value; please, try again.");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I only allow number input into my C# Console Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106493/how-do-i-only-allow-number-input-into-my-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: @tmwoods This code only allows number input. That's not the issue, sorry if I didn't make it clear. The issue is after the first input, the number input seems to break and the cursor goes to a different place and rewrite something its not supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad 1)

Because you have `Console.ReadKey` at the end of `ReadInteger` which will be executed as well. So if you hit `Console.ReadLine` at the line `string input = Console.ReadLine();` and enter something that is not a number, `int.TryParse` will return `false`. This leads to the error message and the execution of `Console.ReadKey`. So you should first of all get rid of that `Console.ReadKey` there.

Ad 2)

You are setting the cursor position **before** the call of `ReadInteger` but not **within** `ReadInteger`. So if someone enters a text, the end of the input is typically done by pressing enter. You then write a line (with `Console.WriteLine`). So if you want to have the cursor at the same position, you will have to reset it's position within the loop which is within the `ReadInteger` method.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this:

```
 public static int ReadInt(string prompt)
 {
     Console.Clear();
     var length = prompt.Length + 2;     //2 is for a colon and a space
     var position = length;
     Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
     string buffer = String.Empty;
     int returnNum = 0;
     while (true)
     {
         Console.SetCursorPosition(position, 0);
         var charRead = Console.ReadKey();
         if(charRead.KeyChar == '\r')
         {
             return returnNum;
         }
         if (!int.TryParse(buffer + charRead.KeyChar, out returnNum))
         {
             Console.SetCursorPosition(position, 0);
             Console.WriteLine(" "); //overwrite
             Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
             Console.Write("Error: enter only digits");
             continue;
         }
         else
         {
             buffer += charRead.KeyChar;
             ++position;
             //overwrite any error
             Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
             Console.Write("                         ");
         }
     }
 }
```

It's not perfect.  It doesn't handle typing in too many digits.  It doesn't handle backspace.  It clears the console to establish position (it doesn't look like you can read the console position, and I'm too lazy to keep track of things).

If you do handle backspace, make sure you don't let users backup too much.  It's been years (um, no, decades) since I've done low level console management, but I can remember doing this in CP/M in the early 80s - if you backed up to far, the OS died (which would be a *very* result in Windows :-) ).

Comment: OK, why the downvote?  This seems to do what the OP asked.  I don't mind being downvoted, but I'd like to learn something in the process.

Comment: OP here, I'm still a beginner. Thanks for the help! I'll come back and try your method when I'm better it's rather confusing to me at the moment.

Comment: @RyanW: It works character by character.  It maintains a buffer of the current number (as a string).  If the user enters a digit, the `TryParse` will succeed and the new character is added to the buffer.  If a non-digit is entered, it does some `SetCursorPos` games to overwrite the bad character (and write an error message on the next line - that message is overwritten on good input).  If a new-line comes in, the current buffer/number is returned. Put a breakpoint on the `ReadKey` call, make sure that VS and your console don't overlap and debugging should show you how it works