# How can I use some data validation to ensure that a letter or a certain number cannot be entered for this array?

Tags: c#, arrays, validation, console

The code is shown below. I would like to make it so a number less than 0 cannot be entered.

```
double[] Fastest = new double[GymRunners];

for (int i = 0; i < GymRunners; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the lane time for lane number {0}: ", i + 1);
    Fastest[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());          
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you want to limit the console capabilities to allow only positive numbers? Or do you want to ask the user to input number (per lane) until (s)he provides a positive one?

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks for the welcome. Yes I want the user to input number until its positive and also so a letter cannot be entered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I only allow number input into my C# Console Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106493/how-do-i-only-allow-number-input-into-my-c-sharp-console-application)

Answer (score 2):

`Double.TryParse` will help validate if the input is of type `double`.
This function will assign the input to the `out` variable if the input is parse-able to `double`.
the condition in `do` `while` will check that the input is positive.

So, try the following:

```
double[] Fastest = new double[GymRunners];

    for (int i = 0; i < GymRunners; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the lane time for lane number {0}: ", i + 1);
            Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Fastest[i]);
        } while (Fastest[i] <= 0);
    }
```

Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0) for more about `TryParse` from Microsoft documentation

Comment: Please try to provide some explanation as well, not just code

Comment: Thank you @PeterCsala for the advice. I have added more explanation and a reference